# as3 MVC Using Arrays as Model Get/Set Variables

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, flash-builder, flashdevelop, fdt

I am relatively familiar with the model-view-controller framework for actionscript 3. I have only used numbers and strings as variables in the model class. Now I am at a project that is basically an overflowing single class. I should have just used mvc from the beginning, but I am at a new job where some people don't know mvc, and well yeah it doesn't matter too much because now we need to use mvc.

So anyway, my question is if you use array variables in the model class, and you have a getter/setter for these array variables, what counts as "setting an array"?

If I have a dispatch CHANGE event for that setter, will this get triggered when you push or unshift something into the array? 
Will it get called when you splice something out?
Will it get called when you change a property of a movieclip inside the array?

thanks!
together we can model-view-control the world!

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Let's assume your code looks something like this:

```
public function get dataArr():Array
{
   return _dataArr;
}

public function set dataArr(val:Array):void
{
   dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
   _dataArr = val;
}
```

Now let's assume you have an object, say `model` that contains these functions. Remember that `get` and `set` functions are basically syntactical sugar. So even though something may look like a simple assignment, it's still a function call.

```
// like calling some function model.setDataArr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
// so event gets dispatched   
model.dataArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// liek calling some function model.getDataArr().push(6);
// so setter never gets called and thus event is not dispatched.  
model.dataArr.push(6);
```

So in short, when you do something like `shift` or `push` or whatever, the event won't get dispatched. `model.dataArr` uses the get function to return your array, and then you're calling methods on that returned array. As the set function never gets called, the event never gets dispatched.

You can see similar scenarios throughout the AS3 API. Take [DisplayObject#transform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#transform) for example. When you just do something like `dispObj.transform.matrix.tx += 10` the internal set function is never called and there is no affect. So you have to actually assign a new transform `dispObj.transform = someTransform` for the set function to get called. The same applies to you - you have to actually assign some array for the set function to be called and your event dispatched.

Comment: ok. well what I want is basically for the event to be dispatched when the array is done being changed. So let's say you have some sorting buttons for an inventory page. The model.dataArr is what is actually displayed on the stage. The view takes a click input and sends it to controller. The controller processes it, and changes stuff around in its own local _controllerDataArr or _tempDataArr maybe. Then say _model.dataArr = _tempDataArr Now dataArr is the correctly sorted array, and it sends a change for the view to update itself. Is this how you would go about doing it?

Comment: That should work - as long as you're doing `_model.dataArr = someArray` the set function will get called and the event dispatched.